# GKE Master Upgrade Failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Yesterday I attempted to upgrade my Google Container Engine cluster from 1.6.0 to 1.6.1 via the web console.

Now the status details shows `Master upgrade to 1.6.1 failed`, and kubectl is `unable to connect to server... i/o timeout` for all commands that I have tried.

Can a master be rolled back or rebuilt via gcloud or another method?

Comment: What zone is your cluster in?

Comment: @RobertBailey us-east1-b

Comment: Additionally if I try to run `gcloud container clusters get-credentials CLUSTER` I get: `Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.`
`WARNING: cluster k8s is not running. The kubernetes API may not be available.`
`kubeconfig entry generated for k8s.`

Comment: You may be able to re-attempt the master upgrade (`gcloud container clusters upgrade --master --cluster-version=1.6.1 CLUSTER`) to resolve your problem. If not, please file a support ticket with google cloud support.

Comment: @AlexKerney Were you able to fix the problem? If so, please post a self-answer so to help the community having similar issue.

Comment: @NaviAujla Robert and Google Cloud Support helped me out over email.